# Alfresco Workflow notification email template

Tags: eclipse, alfresco

I'm new to Alfresco, and I have been trying to customize the email templates for workflow notifications. I have two issues that I appreciate some help with:

- I have accidentally deleted the default template from the repository. When I uploaded it again, it gives me this error when trying to send an email: 
  Exception while invoking TaskListener: Node does not exist: workspace://SpacesStore/wf-email-html-ftl(Status[changeTxnId=fd950a3d-d236-4cb8-b2df-3337187c6aef, dbTxnId=1250, deleted=true])
- Second, I want to include a link to the WF's document in the email sent. For this I need the site id in order to include it in the url of the link to be displayed. I tried to retrieve it from space object but it's not working. (I was testing on the server on which my application was deployed. On my local machine, I am getting the error above in my eclipse project's console, so I'm not being able to test and get the exact error.)

I appreciate any help and Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've you've deleted it, go to your trashcan through the old explorer interface /alfresco.
Or login as admin and go to the trashcan in Share and restore your file.

If you upload the file, it gets a new UUID, so references will be broken.
You don't need the site id in theory. You can browse to the same document through the Repository which doesn't have a site :).
This is an example from my environment: **share/page/document-details?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/fbb062e6-e941-42bf-ade4-3ac3acc05501**

So it's just `/share/page/document-details?nodeRef=<UUID>`